# Установить открываемую клавиатуру (Для EditText) под TextView

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, клавиатура

Возникла необходимость "на лету" отображать в *TextView* результат некоторого вычисления вводимого в *EditText*, но клавиатура перекрывает *TextView*.
Эти два компонента по макету находятся в центре экрана.

Как установить открываемую клавиатуру под *TextView*?

[image: Поле ввода и результат вычисления в TextView]

Answer (score 2):

Выставьте в манифесте у активити `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

После этого клавиатура будет не накладываться сверху на View вашей активити а просто сжимать его.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ заставить клавиатуру сдвинуться вниз:

1. Добавить в ваш *Layout* корневым элементом *ScrollView*
2. Получить id всех элементов в классе активити
3. Используем следующий код для *TextView*

   ```
   editTextField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               /*if(Build.VERSION.SDK.equals("4.1.1")||Build.VERSION.SDK.equals("4.1.2"))
               {

               }
               else
               {*/
               scrollView.scrollBy(0, 150);
               //}
           }
       }, 500);

   }
   ```

   });

Материал взят отсюда: http://www.goobbe.biz/questions/6910207/how-to-set-the-distance-from-soft-keyboard-to-edittext

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать при установке значения в TextView  запрашивать, чтобы этот TextView был на экране:

```
textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, textView.getWidth(), textView.getHeight()
                    + (int)(8f * textView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f));
            textView.requestRectangleOnScreen(rect);
        }
    }, 100);
```